# Find the time taken by the train to cross another cyclist given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A train traveling at $60$ kmph,crosses a cyclist who is cycling at $12$kmph in the opposite direction in 20 sec.Find the time taken by the train to cross another cyclist traveling at $20$kmph in the same direction as the train does.

My Approach:

In the first case when train traveling at $60$ kmph,crosses a cyclist who is cycling at $12$kmph in the opposite direction in 20 sec

$\text{Distance}=(60+12) \cdot (20/\color{red}{60})=36\; \text{km}$

To travel with another cyclist at the speed of $20$kmph,we get

$24$=$40$ . t=$6$/$10$ hrs=(6 . 3600)/(10)=2160 sec

I don't know why i am getting wrong Ans.Can Anyone give me Hint?

Comment: I edited your post remarking the error in red color, you took $1\;\text{hr }=60\;\text{s}$ which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice

$\text{Distance}=(60+12) \cdot (20/\color{red}{3600})=400\; \text{m}$